# Insert into same table multiple times

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need a script to insert into a relationship table. This relationship table had one ID column from table `A`, for example. We added a new column, an ID from table `B`.

Is there a way to `INSERT INTO A SELECT...` for each row in `B`, the `A id` and the `B id`?

I'm trying with a stored procedure (which is not working), but if you have any other suggestion, feel free.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE fixNewIDColumn()
BEGIN 

    DECLARE a_id INT;
    DECLARE b_id INT;
    DECLARE finished_a BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE finished_b BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE a_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM a;
    DECLARE b_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM b;

    OPEN a_cursor;
    BEGIN
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished_a = TRUE;
        a_loop: LOOP

            FETCH a_cursor INTO a_id;

            IF finished_a THEN
                LEAVE a_loop;
            END IF;

            OPEN b_cursor;
            BEGIN
                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished_b = TRUE;

                b_loop: LOOP

                    FETCH b_cursor INTO b_id;

                    IF finished_b THEN
                        SET finished_a = FALSE;
                        LEAVE b_loop;
                    END IF;

                    INSERT INTO a VALUES (a_id, b_id); 

                END LOOP b_loop;
                CLOSE b_cursor;
            END;

        END LOOP a_loop;
        CLOSE a_cursor;
    END;
END
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the cursor??  Why cursor??  Can't you just do `INSERT INTO A FROM SELECT FROM B`?

Comment: @Eric and the `a_id`? This `INSERT` is not working.

Comment: Of course it's not working.  It's just the syntax.  You insert your own columns.  I don't know what columns you want.  You don't put your table structure for tableA and tableB.  How am I suppose to know?

Comment: I need to insert into table `A` for an `a_id` every existing `b_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO A(id)
SELECT id
FROM B
```

Try to use `CROSS JOIN`

```
INSERT INTO A(a_id, b_id)
SELECT a.a_id, b.b_id
FROM TableA a
CROSS JOIN TableB b
```

Comment: It's not working. I need to provide for which `a_id` is the `b_id`.

Comment: @Leonardo That will insert everything in B into A.  What do you mean it's not working?

Comment: Imagine table `A` has 10 records, only with the `a_id` column. Table `B` has 20 records. I created a new column in table `A` which is `b_id`.
So now I need to make the relationship and add for every `a_id` all the 20 `b_id` from table `B`.

Comment: @Leonardo so tablea structure: `TableA(a_id, b_id)`, tableb structure `TableB(b_id)`.  You want to insert `TableB.b_id` into TableA.b_id`?

Comment: the structure is right, but it is every `TableB.b_id` for every distinct `TableA.a_id` into `TableA`

Comment: @Leonardo Run the SELECT without INSERT.  See if it returns the right result or not.